# How to read/fetch Gujarati language in PDF format, using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, multilingual, linguistics

We have a PDF in Gujarati language. How to read it using Python language.

I can read English based PDF document using Python. I want to do the same with a Gujarati based PDF document.

Like this sample PDF in Gujarati language how to read it exactly using Python.
"http://www.dkdave.in/PDF%20Materials/Gujarat/Gujarat%20Special.pdf"

Comment: You're file Consist of Non-Text format, pdf file generate with may be images. so while reading pypdf2 showing empty list.
add what you're tried to code, resolve those problem

Answer (score 0):

that we can achive by importing pypdf2 library